# Warning CS1702 when using Microsoft Identity and building solution

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've looked around for solutions to this bug but have not found one, even on SO. The warning I get is this:

```
(0,0): warning CS1702: Assuming assembly reference 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth, 
Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' matches
'Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35', you may need to supply runtime policy
Validation Complete
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

This is what my `Bin` directory looks like:

[image]

Here's the `packages.config` file:

```
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.11" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

In my `web.config` file, there's the runtime section that looks like this:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.2.0" newVersion="2.0.2.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.2.0" newVersion="2.0.2.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.2.0" newVersion="2.0.2.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

What do I need to do to get rid of this warning?

Comment: Sounds to me like the compiler is finding two versions of the Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll library, the one in your Bin folder and one with a more recent version somewhere else.  Is there a copy in the GAC?

Comment: Did you try deleting and re-adding the dll's?

Comment: Did you try deleting your obj both debug and release folders? As @TonyVitabile mentioned, this error is due to the compiler finding to different versions of the same assembly.

Comment: I tried deleting and putting in new packages but the problem persits.

Comment: If you are using Nuget can you post your packages.config?

Comment: Try opening each reference in a decompiler (ILSpy) and check which version of Microsoft.Owin.dll they reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your project file might still be referencing a previous version of the assembly.

You can quickly check that by selecting the Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth reference under the References in the project, and looking at the properties; but I'd advise you also check the contents of your project file, and check the Reference for that assembly, for example:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.2.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Check that both the reference version, and the HintPath version are what you would expect.

If you look at your solution's Packages folder, you might find multiple versions of Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth still in there, and that could be a clue. (You could rename or delete all the versions you don't want, to see what happens).

If that still doesn't get you far enough, turn up the build logging detail to see if that can provide more clues for you.

To do that, in Visual Studio go to **Tools** > **Options** > **Projects and Solutions** > **Build and Run**, and change the *MSBuild project build log file verbosity* to **Normal** or **Detailed**.

Comment: Not sure this helps if it's a third party library that refrences an old version. I.E we use Json 8, but a library we use references Json 6 (WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext in my case)