# ASP.NET Warning - CS1701: Assuming assembly reference

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

Recently we've started upgrading all our projects to MVC5.  I've done 4 other projects without issue but for some reason this one is throwing 95 warnings.

```
ASPNETCOMPILER : warning CS1701: Assuming assembly reference 'System.Web.Mvc,
Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' matches 'Sy
stem.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
', you may need to supply runtime policy
```

Now I am completely aware of what this warning normally means.  I have looked EVERYWHERE for an incorrect reference, checked every single dependency, even gone so far as to grep every single file in my project folder.  I feel like I've wasted days on this and its driving me bonkers!

Does anyone have any suggestions on debugging this issue?

Comment: You can use the web.config to tell the compiler which version you want to use. Under the configuration element i have<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0-4.0.0.1" newVersion="4.0.0.1"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

Comment: Seen this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22200516/warning-cs1702-when-using-microsoft-identity-and-building-solution

Comment: Clear your local cache, remove the packages folder, and rebuild.

Comment: @NineTails I have appropriate bindings in all of my project web configs.  This is whats driving me crazy!  I have quadruple checked all of them haha.

Comment: If that's true it's probably a cache issue as @Gudgip suggested. Try emptying caches, if still not resolved then just ignore it.

Comment: @Will Yup!  I've searched here a ton for clues as well.  I installed the two MVC5 packages via NuGet for all of my projects in this solution (just like I did for the previous 4 applications that worked fine) and it setup all my web.config files and binding redirects etc.  I have verified them all as well.

Comment: @Gudgip How do I appropriately clear my cache?  I've already tried clearing my local nuget cache, deleting my packages folder, and then doing a nuget reinstall + rebuild.

Comment: I might also add that I set Visual Studio to compile all my views with diagnostic verbosity and I do not see the warning.  I only get the warning when I run msbuild to deploy my project, but its the literal same deploy process I've used for everything

Comment: Have you tried adding a binding redirect (the syntax from nine tail's comment) pointing all previous versions to 5.2.3.0?

Comment: @Will Yup!  When I installed the MVC5 packages via NuGet it actually did all of them for me, but that was something I verified before posting here for sure!

Comment: @NineTails I ran Update-Package –reinstall from the NuGet console which uninstalls and removes all package references and then reinstalls them.  I also tried this after removing my packages folder to ensure it re-downloaded them all.

Comment: Last time I had a similar error and I resolved it by removing all folders inside the /packages folder, then I cleaned the solution and when I rebuilded it again, it worked!

Comment: @joalcego - I closed VS and listed all my nuget caches.  I cleared them and then physically checked all locations and make sure all the folders were empty.  I deleted my packages folder as well.  I reopened Visual Studio and built my application which restored all my packages.  The funny thing is I don't get these warnings in VS, even when I compile views also.  I only get them when I try to deploy via msbuild.